# How to access outer div element in jQuery following scenario?

Tags: jquery

My HTML code is as follows:

```
<div class="ez-checkbox ez-checked">
  <input id="ckbCheckAll" class="custom-check ez-hide" type="checkbox" name=""></input>
</div>
```

Now I want access the outer div of input having `id="ckbCheckAll"`. How can I access it in jQuery? In short I want to check whether the outer div with container input having `id="ckbCheckAll"` has class **ez-checked** or not.

Comment: try using `.parent()` src http://api.jquery.com/parent/

Comment: From what element are you trying to access it from? Seeing your jQuery code would help.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19403521/how-to-access-outer-div-element-in-jquery-following-scenario/19403658#19403658

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this code

```
if(($("#ckbCheckAll").parent().hasClass("ez-checked"))){
alert("exist");
} else {
alert("not exist");
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/988YM/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following:

```
  if($('#ckbCheckAll').parent().hasClass('ez-checked')))
{
//Your code 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
var isExists = $("#ckbCheckAll").closest('div.ez-checkbox').hasClass('ez-checked');
if(isExists)
{
  //Rest of the code goes here 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent/):

```
var $ezCheckbox = $("#ckbCheckAll").parent();
```

You can make sure the parent is definitely an `ez-checkbox` using a selector:

```
var $ezCheckbox = $("#ckbCheckAll").parent(".ez-checkbox");
```

So to check if it has the checked class

```
var isChecked = $("#ckbCheckAll").parent().hasClass(".ez-checked");
```

Answer (score 0):

To access `.ez-checkbox`, use the [parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) method

```
$("#ckbCheckAll").parent(".ez-checkbox");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
var exists = $("#ckbCheckAll").parent().hasClass('ez-checked');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var result =  $('#ckbCheckAll').parent().hasClass('ez-checked')
```

Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#ckbCheckAll").parent("div")
```

This ensures, that the parent is a div container.

Answer (score 0):

```
if( $("#ckbCheckAll").closest(".ez-checkbox").hasClass("ez-checked"))
{
// do your stuff
}
```

reference [hasClass](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)

[closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Answer (score 0):

Parent div call name check:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    if('ez-checked' == $("#ckbCheckAll").parent().attr("class")) {
    alert('yes');
   }
 });
```